# Suddenly my resolution of screen changed and i can't reset back

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

When I update my OS, suddenly the resolution is set to 1024x768. I do everything to change it back to 1920x1080, but nothing helps me. Maybe someone knows how can I solve this problem? I think the problem is in `GPU : EFI`. Does someone know how can I change it to NVIDIA?

`screenfetch` output:

``````
                          ./+o+-       levon@levon-desktop
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 47m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2000
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1024x768
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: GNOME Shell
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i7-7700 @ 8x 4.2GHz [36.0°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: EFI
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 1793MiB / 15977MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

`xrandr` output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1920x1200_60.00 (0x2c1) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x2c2) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080R (0x2c3) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
```

`xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920_1080_60.00` output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI1"
```

`xrandr -q` output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub` content:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

In the image below I show that I use `nvidia-driver-440`.

[image: driver settings]

Comment: Could you add the output of `xrandr -q`?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and ,this was my configuration.
[image]

so went to nvidia site (https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in) and downloaded latest driver and manually installed it

[image]

and after a reboot my issue seems to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

Access terminal from login screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It works. My box has upgraded a lot of package. Can you explain why does it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me this morning. Not exactly sure what caused that. In my case, it seems the monitor was not detected correctly, monitor audio options was not showing in sound. I end up to use other display ports on graphic card and resolution is back.