My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS operating system is stuck at 1024x768 resolution. How do I fix it?
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and everything is working perfectly fine but there's a problem. My display resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and I am using a 1366x768 monitor. In the display settings, the highest resolution is 1024x768. How do I fix it? By the way I have Wayland as my default installed windowing system. Do I need to change it?

Possibly related to the nvidia drivers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210587/suddenly-my-resolution-of-screen-changed-and-i-cant-reset-back
